# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compiler-errors

this code on vb.net is giving me this error :

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

```
     Public Class Family
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    
End Sub
Protected Sub saveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveButton.Click
    Dim clsFamily As New clsFamily
    Session("Family") = clsFamily
    If clsFamily Is Nothing Then

        clsFamily = New clsFamily
    Else
        clsFamily = Session("Family")
    End If
    Dim eror As Integer = 0
    Dim eror_message As String = "Wrong input, please try again"
    If TBxPN.Text Is "" Or TBxPN.Text Is eror_message Or Regex.IsMatch(TBxPN.Text, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
        TBxPN.Text = eror_message
        eror = 1
    End If

    If TBxOcc.Text Is "" Or TBxOcc.Text Is eror_message Or Regex.IsMatch(TBxOcc.Text, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
        TBxOcc.Text = eror_message
        eror = 1
    End If
    If eror = 0 Then
        For i = 0 To clsFamily.PersonName.Length

            Dim newName As String
            Dim newOccupation As String
            Dim newDate As Date
            Dim newGender As String
            Dim newRelation As String

            newName = TBxPN.Text
            newOccupation = TBxOcc.Text
            newDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
            newGender = RBLGender.SelectedItem.Text
            newRelation = CBLRelation.SelectedItem.Text
            ReDim Preserve clsFamily.PersonName(i)
            clsFamily.PersonName(i) = newName
            ReDim Preserve clsFamily.Occupation(i)
            clsFamily.Occupation(i) = newOccupation
            ReDim Preserve clsFamily.DOB(i)
            clsFamily.DOB(i) = newDate
            ReDim Preserve clsFamily.Gender(i)
            clsFamily.Gender(i) = newGender
            ReDim Preserve clsFamily.RelationType(i)
            clsFamily.RelationType(i) = newRelation

        Next i
        Session("Family") = clsFamily


    End If


End Sub
Public Class clsFamily
    Public PersonName() As String
    Public RelationType() As String
    Public DOB() As Date
    Public Gender() As String
    Public Occupation() As String

End Class
```

Comment: In which row is the exception thrown?

Comment: For i = 0 To clsFamily.PersonName.Length

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: clsFamily.PersonName is null, so you can't access the 'Length' member

Comment: @Nissim I noticed that, but even if I added +1 to the length... the same prob occurs

Comment: what is PersonName in clsFamily is it a property or something else?

Comment: PersonName is an array in the class clsFamily

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do need a constructor in your class. Next example adds 1 item to the personName array: "". This means the array is no longer empty so there is no NullReferenceException.

```
Public Class clsFamily
    Public PersonName() As String
    Public RelationType() As String
    Public DOB() As Date
    Public Gender() As String
    Public Occupation() As String


    Public Sub New()
        PersonName = New String(0) {""}
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: To use this method to avoid the NullReferenceException in the OP's code, all the arrays will have to be initialised.